# How does the Communist Party of China (CPC) keep the factions in check?

Tags: china, government

There are several factions within the CPC that compete for power, how does the Chinese government keep them in check to ensure that they don't destroy each other? There are two main factions and some minor ones. The two main factions are:

The princelings are a group of party officials who come from prominent families with revolutionary credentials. They are seen as the heirs of the founding fathers of the People's Republic of China, such as Mao Zedong and Zhou Enlai. They tend to have close ties to the military and the state-owned enterprises and are generally conservative.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princelings

The tuanpai are officials who rose through the ranks of the Communist Youth League, a party organization that recruits young people into the party. They tend to be more liberal in their political views and are associated with reform and opening up policies. They are also more likely to have experience in grassroots work and to be supportive of policies aimed at improving the lives of ordinary people.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuanpai

My questions is how China keeps them in check and prevents them from clashing against each other? It has been reported that Hu Jingtao was publicly humiliated during one of their meetings.

https://www.cnn.com/2022/10/28/china/china-party-congress-hu-jintao-new-video-intl-hnk/index.html

Comment: As these are not entirely formalized concepts, depending how you define "faction"
 and "destroyed" that probably happened in some way a number of times during the party's history. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gang_of_Four for some older example(s).

Comment: Unfortunately, they are already destroyed by Xi JinPing. If he did not displace the parties' own power with his own cliques and "work groups". China may well transform into a more democratic society.

Comment: @Fizz The factions are "the Princelings" (sons of the first generation communists), "the Communist Youth Clique" (groups of "young" leaders promoted from the Communist Youth Organization into the Party structures), and "the Secretaries" (those who started working as big leader's secretaries and climb up the ranks using the ties and connections). There are also some informal groups like "Shanghaiers" (politicians started their work in Shanghai, most usually related to Jiang ZeMin), and Xi JinPing's own "New Army of ZhiJiang" (a group of his own making from inside "the Princelings")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is likely to be quite boring, which is much of CCP's internal working is a black box, even to those closest in the region.

I kind of understand the inherent fascination with these types of things, but we probably won't know CCP's internal politicking until much later. Hypothetically, if CCP collapses in the future, historians would have troves of records and documents to study (like Nazi Germany or Soviet Union). But until then, it's mostly speculation.

I might challenge the implied premise that factional struggle necessarily translates to CCP's party policy - which is the norm in democracies. Rather, each successive CCP leader - perhaps correctly - understands that their hold on power has more to do with the country's economic performance, and less to do with whether they have support of their colleagues (once they are appinted into office, that is). As long as the annual GDP growth stays above 6%, it is unlikely that any amount of factional dissent can drag you down.

This was the case during the era of Deng Xiaoping, Jiang Zemin, and Hu Jintao. For a very long time, the explosion of economic growth took precedence, the focus was on generation of seemingly unlimited wealth, rather than the distribution of finite wealth. Put simply, times were good so the leadership was secured.

This took a turn when Xi Jinping came into office, whose shift in concentration of personal power coincides with a stagnation of economic growth. If economy is no longer a source of political legitimacy, then it must come from the leader's raw power to suppress dissent.

In both cases, the CCP leaders seek to bypass the issue of factional dispute by seeking legitimacy through larger environmental forces, whether it be maintaining a high-growth economy or personalizing the regime. This is actually similar to the dynastic Chinese emperors of the past, who were often deposed due to environmental forces such as drought, famine, disease, corruption, rather than courtly political intrigue.

The party factions exert their influence during the selection of the leader, but less so after the leader is chosen. As Xi had removed his own term limit, it is difficult to see how factional disputes can be relevant for CCP in the forseeable future.

Comment: I want to believe your second to last paragraph since it fits with the concept of the mandate of heaven, but I think it undersells how many emperors were off'ed. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Murdered_Chinese_emperors). The most recent being [in 1908](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guangxu_Emperor)

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph.  Most governing entities (political parties, etc.) have substantial portions of their internal maneuvers in private. The CCP goes farther in this than most. Also, well done for writing about the historical changes in the process.

Answer (score 5):

Research on this can be considered rather tentative, but according to one 2016 NBER [paper](https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w22775/w22775.pdf) your definition/identification of "factions" in the CCP is probably not quite right, i.e. the "pricilings" and the Tuanpai (people who ascended via the CYLC--Communist Youth League of China) don't stand in such a strong opposition to each other. Factions do seem exist, but tend to be mutually exclusive on a narrower basis. That paper suggests that the CYLC faction is more mutually exclusive with the [Shanghai Gang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanghai_clique) rather than all the "princelings". A compromise of sorts between the more mutually exclusive factions seems to be achieved by divvying up the offices. And even in the context of corruption-related purges, some balance is apparently struck.

> Factions have historically emerged
> within the CCP through close personal connections with prominent patrons
> (e.g. in the cases of former General Secretary Jiang Zemin and his successor,
> Hu Jintao) to mutually foster the career prospects of affiliated cadres, and do not necessarily represent specific territorial or economic interest groups. [...]
>
> Based on our factional definitions and within a proximate set of party officials
> of almost equivalent rank in the same office and area (e.g. the number 1 and
> number 2 highest ranked party members in a province), we show that members
> of a faction (let us call it B) are virtually never paired with members of the same
> faction B at the same office. On the contrary, they are paired with members of
> a rival faction (R) beyond what would be predicted by random chance alone.
> For instance, if a province has a B faction Party Secretary (ranked number 1), the Governor (his number 2) is likely to be an R, possibly a neutral o¢cial, but most definitely not a B faction member.
>
> [...]
>
> Following the literature on Chinese politics (Bo, 2008; Li, 2013a; Li, 2013b),
> we construct four a¢liation indicators for the full sample of politicians: CYLC,
> Shanghai Gang, but also Military and Princeling status. A politician is classified as from the CYLC if he/she has held provincial and national level positions in CYLC. A politician is classified as from the Shanghai Gang if he/she
> has held official positions in the Shanghai municipal party apparatus, municipal
> government, municipal People's Congress, and municipal People's Political Con-
> sultative Conference. This again underlies the exceptionality of the Shanghai
> political machine. A politician is classified as from the Military if he/she served
> as military personnel in the Revolutionary Era (1921-1949), or has participated
> in the volunteer armies to Korea or Vietnam, or served as military personnel for
> more than half of its career after the founding of People's Republic of China.
> The restriction on the minimum time of military experience is to rule out civilian
> officials who work as the party secretary of a military region for a short period
> of time (e.g. Hu Jintao as the First Secretary of Guizhou Military District from
> 1985 to 1988), or civilian officials chair the Central Military Commission (e.g.
> Jiang Zemin as the chairman of the Central Military Commission from 1990 to
> 2005). A politician is classified as a Princeling if he/she is from a prominent
> political family, the so called ?red aristocracy? (prominent examples include
> General Secretary Xi Jinping and disgraced former governor of Liaoning Bo Xilai). These four affiliations are not mutually exclusive (for example, Xi Jinping
> is both a princeling and an affiliated of the Shanghai Gang according to our
> definition) and not all party members in our sample are affiliated. In fact, we
> allow for politicians in our sample to also be unaffiliated (neutral, indicated as N).
>
> Theoretically one could consider CYLC, Shanghai Gang, military, and princelings
> alternative political factions. [...] we show however than only two of
> these groups, CYLC and Shanghai Gang, truly exhibit the features of political factions within the CCP.
>
> [...] Anti-Corruption Campaign. As in the allocation of rewards to cofactionals through leadership premia, we would also expect evidence of factional bias
> in the administration of punishment. We have limited systematic evidence in
> this respect, but it interestingly points in a direction consistent with the limited leadership premia [...].
> This novel evidence comes from the factional analysis of the CCP members
> hit by President Xi Jinping’s anti-corruption campaign (initiated in 2012 and
> still ongoing as of 2016). A remarkable factional balance seems to be present
> in the administration of punishment, when looking at the detailed resumes of
> the so-called “tigers”, a code name for high-ranking party members a¤ected
> by the purge . Table 8 shows that both CYLC and Shanghai Gang cadres
> appear represented in the purged sample and, importantly, both factions are
> represented in shares proportional to their overall representation in the upper echelons of the CCP, and not statistically significantly higher or lower. The reader may however notice a lower, but not significant, representation of Shanghai Gang members, the faction most likely to be associated with Xi (if at all).

Whether this 2016-observed balance (in fact most data was only up to 2012) has or will continue in subsequent years, given the apparent entrenchment of the Xi faction, is an interesting [future] research topic.

> [image]

---

However, one 2022 Reuters [article](https://www.reuters.com/world/china/chinas-xi-deals-knockout-blow-once-powerful-youth-league-faction-2022-10-26/) in fact suggests that [prior] balance may have turned into a victory of sorts for one of the aforementioned factions (Xi's obviously), at least at the top level:

> BEIJING, Oct 26 (Reuters) - The three most glaring omissions from China's new Communist Party leadership share one common trait: all rose through its Youth League and were considered members of a once-powerful faction whose influence Xi Jinping has now effectively crushed.
>
> Premier Li Keqiang and Vice Premier Wang Yang, both 67 and young enough to be re-appointed to the elite seven-member Politburo Standing Committee, were left off even the wider Central Committee, as Xi installed loyalists in top party posts during the recent twice-a-decade leadership reshuffle.
>
> Fellow vice premier and one-time high-flyer Hu Chunhua, who, at 59, had been seen by some party watchers as a candidate for premier and once even a possible future president, did not make it to the 24-man Politburo.
>
> The omissions show Xi has succeeded in a years-long effort to eradicate the faction, analysts said. [...]
>
> "They are completely defeated," said Cheng Li, a specialist on the transformation of political leaders in China, referring to the sidelining of the Youth League faction.
>
> "It means Xi can do many things he wants to, and opposing forces have got weaker," added Li, who is with the Brookings Institution in Washington.
>
> "It can be read as, he didn't want the Western-style balance of power and wanted to show more of the centralisation of his power."

And besides personnel, that also seems to have been done with money (allocations):

> The Youth League's budget has been cut from nearly 700 million yuan ($96 million) in 2012, the year Xi assumed power, to about 260 million yuan in 2021, official data shows.

Also interesting perhaps, the 2016 paper said that Xi's connection to the Shanghai clique was rather weak:

> The Vuong test shows that Xi is slightly
> more likely to be a Shanghai Gang member, although the statistical evidence
> is inconclusive. Our tests do not have enough power in this specific instance.

The Reuters article says that Xi essentially has formed his own faction, the ["New Zhijiang Army"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Zhijiang_Army).

---

Thirdly, the balancing observed in the years before Xi may have been a result of circumstances that later failed to replicate. Even before this last Congress, one (2021) paper [wrote](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/china-quarterly/article/from-power-balance-to-dominant-faction-in-xi-jinpings-china/C311C96EB52F5186599E67112E5CB821):

> we investigate whether a dominant faction is emerging under Xi Jinping, replacing the power balancing between factions that was the norm throughout the reform era. Analysing factional affiliations of Chinese leaders in the top four ranks, we find that Xi has formed a dominant faction. Through statistical analysis of the promotion chances of provincial leaders, we find that Xi has been unusually successful when compared to previous leaders at promoting his clients. This suggests that Xi has boosted the power of his faction by elevating provincial leaders to an extent not seen since the death of Mao and Deng.
>
> [...] Previous studies suggest that dominant factions are rare, if not unheard of, in the CCP. [...] When Xi took power, there were only two rival factions, the Shanghai faction led by Jiang Zemin and the CYL faction led by Hu Jintao. Xi had the backing of the Shanghai faction. Additionally, by failing to name a successor, Xi Jinping has prevented an obvious nucleus around which a new rival faction could form. [...]
>
> When Jiang Zemin suddenly took
> the position of CCP general secretary following the suppression of the
> Tiananmen movement in 1989, his power was constrained by the revolutionary
> generation led by Deng Xiaoping. Similarly, when Hu began to govern in
> 2002, five of the-then nine members of the Politburo Standing Committee, the
> most influential positions in the CCP, belonged to Jiang’s faction.28 In contrast,
> when Xi took power in 2012, only one of the seven members of the Standing
> Committee was from Hu’s faction. As we would expect, Xi’s faction was generally
> weaker than Hu’s faction when Xi became CCP leader in 2012. However,
> because Jiang’s faction supported Xi and still had a powerful presence in the
> Standing Committee, Xi actually enjoyed more influence in the Standing
> Committee on his first day in office than Hu ever did. Moreover, Xi took the position
> of chairman of the Central Military Commission at the same time as he
> became general secretary in 2012. In contrast, Hu only assumed this position
> two years after becoming the general Party secretary. These conditions may
> have provided Xi with an opening to build up his faction quickly.
> Third, Xi Jinping launched a massive anti-corruption campaign that targeted
> both “tigers” (high-level officials) and “flies” (lower-level officials). By punishing
> Zhou Yongkang 周永康, a previous member of the Standing Committee of the
> Politburo, Xi signalled that a top leadership position was no longer protection
> against corruption investigations. Intimidating high-ranking leaders with the possible
> threat of corruption charges probably helped Xi to undermine opposition to
> his consolidation of power, strengthen his own faction and weaken his rivals’ factions.
>
> Measuring the strength of factions is challenging, but considering that factional
> struggle is fierce in personnel appointments, the proportions of official positions
> taken by factions indicate the strength of a faction. We examine four top-ranking
> positions within the Chinese hierarchy: the Standing Committee of the Politburo,
> the Politburo, provincial Party secretaries and provincial governors.
>
> It is challenging to identify factional ties in Chinese elite politics since the official
> policy of the CCP is that factions are prohibited. We follow Cheng Li in
> identifying factional ties that are formed based largely on experience of working
> in the same unit during an overlapping period of time. This criterion clearly satisfies
> three of the four core attributes of the concept of factions: face-to-face interaction,
> longevity and power inequality. The fourth criterion, interest exchange, is
> less clear owing to its clandestine nature. In order to identify every factional
> member in the four ranks, we reviewed the secondary literature on factional
> affiliations as well as the biographies of provincial leaders to determine whether
> they had worked with Jiang Zemin, Hu Jintao or Xi Jinping. If so, we coded
> them as belonging to one of these factions.
>
> Jiang Zemin’s faction evolved mostly through the ties he cultivated during his
> time in Shanghai.[...] Hu Jintao’s faction was born from his links with the CYL and is therefore sometimes called the CYL faction.
>
> We use Cheng Li’s analyses of Xi Jinping’s inner circles to identify Xi’s clients.
> He points to three bases for Xi’s connections: [...]
> Xi Jinping himself spent several years in Shaanxi during the Cultural Revolution
> as a “sent-down youth.” [...] Chen Xi
> 陈希is included in the Xi faction on the basis of having become acquainted with
> Xi while both attended Tsinghua University. The provincial leaders in the Xi
> faction developed a relationship with Xi when he worked in several provinces,
> including Hebei, Fujian, Zhejiang and Shanghai. We identify those who had
> overlapping work experience with Xi in these regions as his clients. In total, we
> identify 23 provincial leaders to be Xi’s clients.
>
> In Figure 1, we compare the strength of factions led by the ruling head of the
> CCP with those led by the former head of the CCP in the Hu and Xi eras.
> The number represents the proportions of factional members out of the total
> number of positions at that level.
>
> [image]
>
> These figures indicate a similarity in the life cycle of factions. When a leader
> first becomes head of the CCP, his faction is relatively weak at the highest levels.
> During his time in power, his faction gains in strength. The strength of Jiang’s
> and Hu’s factions peaked the years they retired, 2002 and 2012, respectively.
> Following their retirement, their factions began to weaken. This is typical for personalized
> factions because they depend on clientelist ties between the faction head
> and followers. [...]
>
> When Xi took power, his faction was generally as weak as his predecessors’
> had been. However, Xi strengthened his faction much more quickly than his
> two immediate predecessors did. In 2018, Xi’s faction took 43 per cent of the
> seats on the Standing Committee of the Politburo; 56 per cent of the seats on
> the Politburo; 42 per cent of provincial Party secretaryships, and 26 per cent of
> provincial governorships. Even when we compare Hu’s faction and Xi’s faction
> in the first year of their second terms (See Figure 1, C and H), we find that Xi’s
> faction held much higher shares of the seats in each rank – except among provincial
> governors, the lowest rank among the four.
>
> Jiang Zemin had a narrower base of support than was the case for Hu
> Jintao or Xi Jinping. Prior to his appointment as CCP general secretary,
> Jiang’s career was mostly confined to Shanghai. On the other hand, Hu
> Jintao’s power base was the CYL, a nationwide organization. Xi Jinping had a
> wider pool of connections partly because he was a princeling and partly because
> he had worked in different locations including Hebei, Fujian, Zhejiang and
> Shanghai.
>
> Table 2 shows that from 1993 to 1998, 56 provincial Party secretaries failed to
> gain promotion. Among the four who were promoted, half were Jiang’s clients.
> This clearly shows the disproportionately high chance for promotion that factional
> membership provided. During the first six years of Hu’s rule, six provincial
> Party secretaries were promoted while 48 were not. Among those promoted, two
> belonged to Hu’s faction, two were affiliated with Jiang’s faction and two had no
> factional ties, indicating not only the power of factional affiliation but also a
> power balance between factions. Table 2 shows that Xi’s clients netted four out
> of the seven promotions handed out from 2013 to 2018, while two of Hu’s clients
> and one of Jiang’s clients were promoted during this period. In short, Xi promoted
> twice as many of his clients to Politburo-level positions as did Jiang
> Zemin or Hu Jintao during the equivalent period of their rule.
>
> [image]
>
> The uniqueness of the Xi era is even more noticeable at the gubernatorial level,
> as shown in Table 3. In the first six years of the Jiang administration, only three
> of Jiang’s gubernatorial clients were promoted whereas 17 governors without factional
> ties were promoted. Similarly, in the first six years of the Hu era, only two
> out of Hu’s 17 gubernatorial clients were promoted while 14 governors without
> factional ties gained promotion. In contrast, in the first six years of the Xi administration,
> his gubernatorial clients obtained 13 promotions. These figures offer
> clear evidence that Xi’s clients are more likely to be promoted.

So yeah, the previously observed balancing may have been due to somewhat complicated factors, including weaker factions with less interconnections and the time-limited opportunity to elbow out the opposition more definitively.

Regarding corruption investigation at the top, Wikipedia [notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhou_Yongkang):

> Zhou's case was unprecedented, as no corruption investigation had ever been initiated against a member of the elite Politburo Standing Committee. [...] the last PSC members to be put on trial were those of the Gang of Four following the Cultural Revolution.